# Unable to push aura component to org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

this is my aura component for custom page layout -

```
<aura:component implements ="lightning:recordHomeTemplate" description ="Main region with expandable drawer" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="header" type ="Aura.Component[]" description="Header region"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="drawer" type ="Aura.Component[]" description="Drawer region"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="isDrawerOpen" type ="Boolean" access="PRIVATE" default="false"/> 

    <div class="{! v.isDrawerOpen ? 'drawer-open': ''}">
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto">
                <div class="header-region">
                    {!v.header}
                </div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem class="drawer-container">
                <lightning:buttonIcon   onclick="{c.toggleDrawer}"
                                        title=""
                                        class="design-allow-interaction toggle slds-p-around_xxx-small"
                                        variant = "border-filled"
                                        iconName="utility:chevronleft"
                                        alternativeText ="{!v.isDrawerOpen ? 'Collapse drawer': 'Expand drawer'"/>                
                <div class="region-drawer">
                    {!v.drawer}
                </div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

this is the controller class -

```
({
    toggleDrawer : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isDrawerOpen", !component.get("v.isDrawerOpen"));
    }
})
```

design -

```
<design:component label="Main, Collapsiblle Drawer for Phone">
    <flexipage:template>
        <flexipage:region name="header" defaultWidth ="SMALL" />
        <flexipage:region name ="drawer" defaultWidth = "SMALL"/>
    </flexipage:template>
    <design:supportedFormFactors>
        <design:supportedFormFactor type = "SMALL"/>
    </design:supportedFormFactors>
</design:component>
```

While deploying the source to org, I am getting this error -

**Unterminated expressionAuraDefinitionBundle**

I have not worked much on Aura so maybe I am not getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
alternativeText ="{!v.isDrawerOpen ? 'Collapse drawer': 'Expand drawer'"/>
```

Is missing a `}`. I realize the error is a bit cryptic, but just remember that `{!...}` are *expressions*, so an error that contains "expression" typically has something to do with an expression.